# How to keep the date in Airflow execution date and convert time to 00:00

Tags: python, date, airflow

I'm using `time_marker = {{execution_date.in_timezone('Europe/Amsterdam')}}` in my dag.py program. I'm trying to keep the date part in execution date, and set the time to `"T00:00:00"`
So whenever during the execution date it runs, the time_marker will always be for example `20240115T00:00:00`

How should I do this? I tried to use pendulum.parse but didn't work out how to do this. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add a custom macro to the DAG definition

Function:

```
def format_execution_date(execution_date):
    amsterdam_time = execution_date.in_timezone('Europe/Amsterdam')
    midnight_amsterdam_time = amsterdam_time.start_of('day')
    return midnight_amsterdam_time.format('YYYYMMDDT00:00:00')
```

Use function:

```
with DAG(
...

    user_defined_macros={'format_execution_date': format_execution_date},

) as dag:
...
```

In your task, you can used by:

```
params={
    'time_marker': '{{ format_execution_date(execution_date) }}'
}
```